# Keep getting string index out of range error in code

Tags: python

I keep getting the `IndexError: string index out of range`, and am wondering what I'm doing wrong with the code.

```
inFile=open('pa7.cards','r')
cardnum=inFile.readline().strip()

def main():
    while cardnum!='99999':
        Step1(cardnum)
def CheckLen(num):
    if len(num)>=13 and len(num)<=16:
        return True
    else:
        return False
def Step1(num):
    total=0
    for i in range(len(num)-2,0,-2):
        if eval(num[i]*2)>=10:
            i=eval(num[i])*2
            i=str(i)
            i=eval(i[0])+eval(i[1])
            total+=i
        else:
            total+=i
    return total
def Step2(num):
    total=0
    for i in range(len(num)-1,0,-2):
        total+=i
    return total
def Step3(num):
    total=Step1(num)+Step2(num)
    if total%10==0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
##def DetermineType(num):
main()
```

This is what the input file looks like:

```
4388576018402626 
4388576018410707 
37271983 
99999
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Andrew/Desktop/pa7.py", line 47, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Andrew/Desktop/pa7.py", line 18, in main
    Step1(cardnum)
  File "C:/Users/Andrew/Desktop/pa7.py", line 30, in Step1
    i=eval(i[0])+eval(i[1])
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: What about use `int()` instead of `eval()`?

Comment: it gives the same error

Comment: Yeah...just say that you could use `int()` instead of `eval()`. However, never use `eval()`. About that error, `i = int(i[0])+int(i[1])` I think `i`'s length is 1 so you can't do something like `i[1]`.

Comment: Agree with Kevin. For i<10 `str(i)` will generate string length one which then causes the error in `i[1]`

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a few Bad Things<sup>TM</sup> there.

The source of your error is that `i` is built by taking a digit from your "number string", doubling it and converting it back to a string (so `"8"` becomes `"16"`).

Then you try and access `i[1]` - which is out of range if `i` is only 1 character long.

But there are more problems - reusing the name `i` within the  `for` loop, using `eval()` (shudder!) where `int()` would do, iterating over a string using `range()` instead of slices...

For example,

```
for i in range(len(num)-2,0,-2):
```

should be

```
for digit in num[-2:0:-2]:
```

Comment: okay so im not to strong in slices yet, but i've tried to make changes to the code, this is what i did, though it just gives me an infinite loop:

Answer (score 0):

```
def Step1(num):
    total=0
    for digit in num[-2:0:-2]:
        digit=int(digit)

        if int(num[digit])*2>=10:
            x=int(num[digit])*2
            x1=str(x)
            x2=int(x1[0])+int(x1[1])
            total+=x2
        else:
            x=int((num[digit]))
            total+=x
    return total
```